# ANTLR4 matching a string with a start cha and end character

Tags: match, antlr4

I am trying to write antlr grammar so that I can create a match on a certain ID.

I need to match a character that starts with the character 'n' and ends with 'd'
And this ID can have space.
Everywhere else I want to ignore the whitespace

```
// lexer/terminal rules start with an upper case letter
ID
  :
    (
    'a'..'z'
    | 'A'..'Z'
    | '0'..'9' 
    | ('+'|'-'|'*'|'/'|'_')
  | '='
  | '~'  
  | '{'
  | '}'
  | ','
  | NA
  )+ 
  ;

NA : 'n'[ ]['a'..'z']'d' ;

WS : [ \t\n]+ -> skip;
```

I tested this with an expression A1=not attempted

It considers A1=not as an ID and attempted as an error node

Can you have a grammar that ignore white spaces but makes an exception for a certain string as "not attempted"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to seperate `ID ("A1")` from the rest. Further you need to take care on the priority of lexical rules. Your "n...d" should have higher priority, so take it as one of your first lexer rules.

A working grammar (only tested for your example "A1=not attempted" is:

```
statement : ID expr;

expr : OP expr
     | (NA | ID | OP)
     ;

NA : 'n'[a-zA-Z ]*'d' ;

ID
  : (
    'a'..'z'
    | 'A'..'Z'
    | '0'..'9' 
    | ('+'|'-'|'*'|'/'|'_')
    )+ ;

OP : '='
  | '~'  
  | '{'
  | '}'
  | ','
  ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Try it with start rule `statement`. I changed the NA Rule so it will match zero or more characters a to z and A to Z and Whitspace in any order.

Good Luck with ANTLR, its a nice tool.